# Store output of a command in a variable

Tags: bash, shell, quotes

In my mac terminal I am trying to store the output of a command into a variable like this

```
$ animals=$(cat animals.txt | head -n $plusOne | tail -n $numberofanimals | sort -u | sed -E "s/[*#/@2]//g; s/D/d/g ; s/G/g/g ; s/E/e/g ; s/H/h/g ; s/O/o/g ; s/C/c/g ; s/[!]//g”)
>
```

but it does not work. When I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> I get a `>`  prompt on the next line. Any idea why?

Comment: I have added an image explaining what I mean @lurker

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem, but it looks like you need to escape the `/` in your first regex: `s/[*#\/@2]//g;`. John Kugelman identified the actual problem (multi-byte character double quote at the end instead of ASCII double quote).

Comment: `”` is not `"`. They are not interchangeable.

Comment: `cat | head | tail` can be completely done with sed.  Unless the sort depends on the translations you're doing with the sed, you can replace the entire pipeline with `sed -e "1,$(($plusOne - $numberofanimals))d" -e 's/[*#/@2!]//' -e 'y/DGEHOC/dgehoc/' -e "${plusOne}q" animals.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a smart quote `”` at the end of the line instead of a regular double quote `"`.

Comment: Doesn't this make the question close-as-typo eligible? (Granted, not so much a typo as a copy/paste from software that was built for word processing or publishing rather than software development).

Comment: It does. I already voted and retracted so I couldn't re-vote.